# Prevent screen-lock / sleep-lock / password-lock / etc on Windows 10

Tags: windows, sleep

I have a computer-based test that takes several hours to complete.

However, the test is timed-out at some point, because my PC "goes to sleep in one way or another".

This is possibly related to the fact that the test consists of two processes which communicate with each other via port, so I'm suspecting that perhaps networking is disabled in some way (even if it's completely "local networking").

I have disabled both `screen turn off` and `sleep` in the *Settings* "page", under *Power & Sleep*.

Still no luck, the screen is locked with a password at some point, which I suspect causes the test to stop running in the background.

I even followed a procedure that I found on the web to disable screen-lock via Regedit in something like 18 steps (why on earth did this company figure out that this is a reasonable user experience).

Is there a solution to this problem?

Comment: Screen lock is controlled by the screen saver (but may well be force on via group policy).

Comment: This does not seem to be a programming problem, so I will see if it can be put on hold.

Answer (score -1):

Found a (very hacky) solution:

If you keep all windows minimized, then the screen doesn't get locked.

What a great operating system, by such a great company!!!

Answer (score -1):

Solution in [TXR Lisp](https://nongnu.org/txr).

Save the file below in `nolock.tl`, then run `txr-win nolock.tl`.

E.g. out of a `.bat` file:

```
@noecho
start txr-win nolock.tl
```

(`txr-winl.exe` is a flavor of `txr.exe` which starts without a console window).

While the lock is disabled, a modal dialog box is shown. When you click the OK button to dismiss, the previous system state is restored.

```
(typedef UINT uint)
(typedef HWND (cptr HWND))

(defsymacro NULL cptr-null)
(defsymacro MB_OK #x00000000)
(defsymacro MB_ICONWARNING #x00000030)

(typedef EXECUTION_STATE uint)

(defsymacro ES_CONTINOUS #x80000000)
(defsymacro ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED #x00000002)

(with-dyn-lib "user32.dll"
  (deffi MessageBox "MessageBoxW"
         int (HWND LPCWSTR LPCWSTR UINT)))

(with-dyn-lib "kernel32.dll"
  (deffi SetThrExecState "SetThreadExecutionState"
         EXECUTION_STATE (EXECUTION_STATE)))

(with-resources ((prevstate (SetThrExecState (logior ES_CONTINOUS
                                                     ES_DISPLAY_REQUIRED))
                            (SetThrExecState prevstate)))
  (MessageBox NULL "Screen lock disabled\n\runtil you click OK." "NoLock"
              (logior MB_OK MB_ICONWARNING)))
```

You can download TXR for Windows from [here](https://www.kylheku.com/txr-downloads): look for `TXR-<version>-Win64.exe` (64 bit installer) or `TXR-<version>-Win32.exe` (32 bit installer).

The installer puts the executable directory into the `PATH`, so then the `txr` and `txr-win` commands become available.

There is a way to turn the above small program into an executable not requiring a batch file launcher.

Comment: Although downvoting means "this answer is not useful" (see the hover tooltip), this solution works perfectly. This is what I'm using to prevent screen lock.